# count active inactive deleted results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to count the number of active results in MySQL database to display to the user 
but I can only count the number of rows but I cannot seem to count how many active/inactive/deleted there is

```
<?php
  $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $query = $this->custom_query("SELECT post_status FROM listings WHERE user_id=$user_id ");
  if($query->num_rows()>0){
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
      if($row->post_status == 'active'){
        echo $row->num_rows();
      }
    }                   
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with sql count function, look here for how works count function https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

for answer;

```
select count(id) as active_count from listings WHERE user_id=$user_id and post_status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this modified code with modified sql statement.

Multiple counts in one query.

```
 <?php
      $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

      $query = $this->custom_query("SELECT 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN post_status = 'active' THEN 1 END) as active_total,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN post_status = 'inactive' THEN 1 END) as inactive_total,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN post_status = 'deleted' THEN 1 END) as deleted_total
        FROM listings WHERE user_id = $user_id");

        $row = $query->result();

        echo "Active: ".$row[0]->active_total."<br/>\n";
        echo "Inactive: ".$row[0]->inactive_total."<br/>\n";
        echo "Deleted: ".$row[0]->deleted_total."<br/>\n";
?>
```

Comment: If the above works, you after may wanna convert it to use prepared statements for failure safe and to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to count your retrieved database record is to use `num_rows` with your query

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
return $this->db->get_where('listings', array('user_id'=> $user_id, 'post_status' => 'active'))->num_rows();
```